# Cloning git subtree without downloading whole repo

Tags: git, subdirectory, git-clone

I need to clone [native_client_sdk](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/native_client_sdk/src/BUILDING.rst) subdir from Chromium repository, because repository is huge and I don't have resources to download it. The answer [Is there any way to clone a git repository's sub-directory only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/is-there-any-way-to-clone-a-git-repositorys-sub-directory-only) doesn't help, because git is still downloading the whole repo.

```
$ git init
$ git remote add -f origin https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src
Updating origin
remote: Sending approximately 4.44 GiB ...
remote: Counting objects: 222129, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (438/438)
Receiving objects:   0% (6064/7199440), 3.07 MiB | 174.00 KiB/s
```

Comment: The answer by Jorg answers your question. You need to look for sparse clone/fetch

Comment: *repository is huge and I don't have resources to download it* take a laptop and go to a cafe with free wifi?

Comment: @ace my SSD is too small.